# Keyboard layout seems wrong only in certain windows

Tags: debian-jessie, tightvnc, beaglebone

It seems like any textboxes in lxqt windows is using the wrong characters when typing them. For example the desktop preferences window, trying to type in a new background image file name the keyboard characters are mapped incorrectly but in VIM, shells, etc it's fine.

I checked the locale and keyboard layout and it looks ok.

Comment: What keyboard layout are you using, and what are the discrepancies?

Comment: By default the layout list is empty and generic 101 keyboard is selected. THis is over TightVNC btw